# Xamarin Test Cloud with Appium

Tags: java, xamarin, appium, calabash

Had anyone used Xamarin Test cloud with Appium and tests written in Java and cucumber?
Does it work well?

The reason I'm asking is that we've just started our new mobile app and we decided ti Calabash with Ruby for our test framework running on Xamarin Test Cloudwhen we realised we have a bunch of existing java libraries we would like to reuse for our tests. Calabash doesn't support Java so we have 2 choices:

- We use Appium on the Xamarin Cloud
- We try using Jruby (even though I am not sure it would work with Calabash)
- The only other option left is moving away from Xamarin and using AWS Device Farm instead which supports Appium well for sure.

**Update on August 2016**:

we got in touch with Xamarin Cloud and they told us they are about to release support for appium with Java

Comment: Why don't use Xamarin Test Recorder?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think it is not possible to run Appium tests which are written in JAVA on Xamarin Test cloud and it's a not best practice to do that ATM .

I myself a Lead Java dev saying this and we reverted back to calabash which works magic with XAMARIN TEST CLOUD (we have Native apps on IOS and Android). I am not saying Appium is not good but when it comes to quick feedback and more coverage CALABASH is a good option.

can I ask you why u want to use appium on xamarin (any particular reason)?

Comment: we wrote a set of java libraries which we already use for testing the back end api that we would like to reuse. for instance those libs already have the functionalities of creating a user with all the properties needed and much more. 
when testing the IoS app we will still need to create a user as part of our tests and we would need to rewrite all that code in ruby just because Calabash doesn't support Java.

Comment: And also changing Frameworks ,best practises  for using back end api calls in APPIUM tests is not a good Practice as the scenarios are for user prospective and the tests will become brittle as ur functionality increases .we used the same pattern which u want to use and it became a mess and we had to chosse different path ...so be carefull ...

Answer (score 0):

1. Still xamarin guys integrating Appium framework in xamarin test cloud, Appium will soon be a fully supported framework.
2. The Appium automation framework and its multiple language bindings, including Java, JavaScript, Python, and PHP.